# Expect script fails when running from cron but works when run manually

Tags: linux, shell, cron, expect

I have a script in Linux that creates a file which once created it executes an Expect script that uploads the created file to an SFTP server. I have this running in cron and for whatever reason the upload always fails, however when I execute the script in the shell the upload is successful. I checked the logs and they're not really telling me where the process is going wrong.

**Here's the shell script**

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /home/mysql/paradata/repoupload || exit
mv /mnt/restrictedreports/Restricted/Corporate/Accounting/GL2013/gldetail.csv /home/mysql/paradata/repoupload 2>/dev/null
mv /mnt/restrictedreports/Restricted/Corporate/Accounting/GL2013/vgldetail.csv /home/mysql/paradata/repoupload 2>/dev/null




test -f gldetail.csv && ./SAFCO.sh
test -f vgldetail.csv && ./SAFCO.sh


if [ -f vgldetail.csv ]; then filename=vgldetail.csv; fi
if [ -f gldetail.csv ]; then  filename=gldetail.csv; fi


if [ $filename == gldetail.csv ];
then
./uploadsafco.exp REPOEX > lastftplogsafco.txt
else
 ./uploadvafco.exp REPOEX > lastftplogvafco.txt
fi
```

**Here's the expect script**

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f


set force_conservative 0 ;# set to 1 to force conservative mode even if
;# script wasn't run conservatively originally
if {$force_conservative} {
set send_slow {1 .1}
proc send {ignore arg} {
sleep .1
exp_send -s -- $arg
}
}

set arg1 [lindex $argv 0]

set timeout 30
expect_after {
        timeout { puts "Timeout"; exit 1 }
}
spawn sftp not@this
match_max 100000
expect "password: "
send -- "notapassword\r"
expect -exact "\r
sftp> "
send -- "cd /usr/data/r1/ED\r"
expect "sftp> "
send -- "progress\r"
expect -exact "progress\r
Progress meter disabled\r
sftp> "
send -- "put REPOEX\r"
expect "sftp> "
send -- "chmod 777 REPOEX\r"
expect "sftp> "
send -- "bye\r"
expect eof
exit
```

Comment: You're not specifying the full path to `sftp` -- is it available in cron's PATH for the user?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Works manually, fails in cron" is almost always due to one of these:

- differences in environment variables: `PATH` and others;
- different current working directory;
- lack of a TTY (probably not an issue with expect scripts);
- permissions (interactive testing with one user, cron job with another); or
- different shell: commands executed in within the cron command line itself use one shell, you may be interactively using another.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problem with my spawn telnet script. Script work fine until adding expect_after for handle timeout.
Try remove expect_after { .. }. It's work for me.