# Script executes but fails when running from cron

Tags: shell-script, cron, python, macos

(macOS Catalina 10.15.7)

I am creating cronjobs with `python-crontab` that look similar to:

```
14 22 5 12 * . ~/.zshrc; zsh ~/Documents/projects/automating-teams/script.zsh Sprint Retrospective
```

I believe this first sets all the required environment variables for the script to execute properly, then executes the script.

The script in question looks like:

```
#!/bin/zsh
cd ~/Documents/projects/automating-teams/
source myenv/bin/activate
python automating_teams.py $1 > ~/Desktop/listener.log 2>&1
```

The python script that is executed uses `pyautogui` to locate and click images to automate the process of joining of Microsoft Teams meetings (an amazing project, I know).

When running `. ~/.zshrc; zsh ~/Documents/projects/automating-teams/script.zsh` manually **using a shell with cron's environment** ([using this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2546509/12379739)) the program works successfully, however, if I allow a cronjob to execute this command, `pyautogui` fails to find my images.

[This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/381517/445111) describes the common issues with cron jobs - I believe I am covering all these as I have given cron full disk access and I am setting my environment before I execute the script.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sourcing `~/.zshrc` in the crontab assumes that the shell executing the jobs is `zsh`. Is it? It's usually `sh`.  It would be better to source the file (possibly conditionally) from within the script itself. I would also factor out everything relevant from `~/.zshrc` into a separate dot script. It is seldom necessary or wanted to invoke the shell startup files for an interactive shell from a cron job (especially if those files start services and/or other programs that only makes sense to run interactively).

Comment: Is there a way to make cron execute with `zsh`? Changing the shell property?